# Why is my MySQL query fast when I do it this way and slow when I do it this way?

Tags: mysql, sql

I need to keep track of users who are online on my site so I can show a "online" icon next to the avatars of users who are online.

The first step of detecting this is to keep track of when the user was last seen so I am doing an UPDATE query each time the user requests a page:

```
UPDATE `users`
SET `last_seen` = CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
WHERE `user_id` = '$user_id'
```

Now right after this, I execute another query, this one gets all the users of my site under certain criterion so I can display them on the homepage:

```
SELECT *,
(ACOS(SIN(0.7103989219783) * SIN(RADIANS(users.latitude)) + COS(0.7103989219783) * COS(RADIANS(users.latitude)) * COS(RADIANS(users.longitude) - -1.2894447135174)) * 6371) AS SearchRadius
FROM `users`
INNER JOIN `profiles` ON (
    users.user_id = profiles.user_id
)
WHERE (users.latitude > 38.904216788163 AND users.latitude < 42.501503211837)
AND (users.longitude > -76.252301637251 AND users.longitude < -71.507178362749)
AND (ACOS(SIN(0.7103989219783) * SIN(RADIANS(users.latitude)) + COS(0.7103989219783) * COS(RADIANS(users.latitude)) * COS(RADIANS(users.longitude) - -1.2894447135174)) * 6371) < 200 AND users.sex = '1' AND users.seeking = '2' AND users.user_id != '1' AND users.account_status = '1' LIMIT 0, 10
```

Never mind the craziness of this query, basically the point is I am selecting from the same `users` table that I was previously updating.

When I execute these 2 queries one after another these are the times I get:

```
1st query: 0.0392 seconds
2nd query: 1.5396 seconds
```

This causes a noticeable delay in page load time.

Now when I created a separate table for online users and change the first query to this:

```
UPDATE `online_users`
SET `last_seen` = CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
WHERE `user_id` = '$user_id'
```

The times changed to this:

```
1st query: 0.0411 seconds
2nd query: 0.0008 seconds
```

and the page loads much faster!

Why is this? My guess is that it has something to do with table locking but I don't know enough to be sure or know more details.

Comment: Does the second query still return the correct results?

Comment: If you run the second query without the first at all is it faster?  It could be some kind of I/O issue - I'm not up on MySQL internals, but that shouldn't be the kind of thing that's blocking in the SQL sense, after all it's either on the same connection in the same transaction, in which case it's allowed to see uncommitted changes or the changes are already committed.  Are you using InnoDB or MyISAM?

Comment: @Cade Roux If I run the 2nd query alone it is faster but only by a minute amount at 0.0004. I am using MyISAM.

Comment: @Russell Zahniser yes it does. The 2nd query shouldn't be affected by the first at all in terms of what it's selecting.

Comment: EXPLAIN EXPLAIN EXPLAIN - that will answer your question

Comment: @JakeRow123 Try it on InnoDB - I'm guessing maybe it's waiting for the write to commit because of MyISAM table-locking limitations.

Comment: Explain could show nothing. I had the same situation. And in the dev environment I've found out that if you do tables optimization then the NEXT time (for 1 time) the times of 'first' query are the same small as the 'second'. The next investigation yield a solution. When I made MySQL to use the right index by 'USE INDEX' the situation was solved. EXPLAIN didn't show meaningful difference and still the question WHY it works this way is unanswered for me.

Comment: Are the results consistent across multiple tests?  Perhaps it is related to caching.

Answer (score 1):

Because `SELECT *` includes `last_seen` MySQL cannot cache the query or subqueries. You might try an explicit enumeration of all fields but `last_seen`.

(But a separate table `online_users` makes much sense.)

Comment: just tried it with an explicit call to all column names except last_seen and the query time was still the same length.

Comment: So we are wiser; simply updating the same table deletes _all_ cached query data of that table. Or something obscure like thread allocation per table, and disk write-back of update.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the `SELECT` query is running several times prior to your test, you're likely seeing the effects of the query cache. Any update on the table will invalidate the cache, and force the query to be executed again. By updating a different table, you're avoiding clobbering those cache entries.

Comment: this makes sense, but in my case I have that query executing only once and that's after the update query.

Comment: Note that you can confirm this with `SET SESSION query_cache_type=OFF;` before running any other commands. (This will only disable the query cache for the current connection.)

Answer (score -4):

query on innoDB table is slower than on MyISAM.
more rows in table make query more slow.
wrong indexing on table make query more slow, check with EXPLAIN command.